# CSS centered image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one question about image centering.

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/PwmwzX)** from codepen.io.

In this demo you can see i have used background image for centering it looks good for me.

The image normalize looking like this: **[NORMALIZE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blx5O.jpg)**

The question is how can use `img` tag instead of `background` and change the html like:

```
<div class="centered-image">
<img src="IMAGE-URL"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display: flex` and let the `img` tag have `width:100%`. [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbdQow)

```css
.centered-img{
  width:540px;
  height:200px;
  margin:0px auto;
  margin-top:50px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.centered-img img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered-img">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BXo4qAz.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new.  MDN Reference: [css flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

Comment: @Robert yes i think my question is good for design. The answer is very basic and usefully. Thanks again for Ben

Answer (score 1):

Vertical centering is most easily done with flex box. This will also center horizontally.

```
.centered-image {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

You still need to set proportions on `.centered-image`, because it would otherwise just stretch to the height of the image and there wouldn't be any vertical alignment happening.

Please check this [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdRxvp). I resized the image to demonstrate the aligning, even on smaller screens.

Comment: Your answer is good. It is what i need to do. But the @ben user is gave me the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
img{
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/k37125ux/

```
html, body{
   height: 100%;
}
.centering-image{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   height: 100%;
}
```